# Installing Fuseki Server in Debian OS

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, fuseki, geosparql

I tried to install the Fuseki server in Debian os by the following instruction at https://gist.github.com/nichtich/113ecc2831d01eb4ae91508b88c0217c but I am not able to start the server.

After running the command

```
./fuseki-server
```

I am getting the below error

```
bash: ./fuseki-server: No such file or directory
```

How to install and run fuseki server as a service in Debian OS?

Comment: which Fuseki version did you install based on the link? Also, I'm pretty sure you did not change into the directory as stated: `cd fuseki` - did you do this?

Comment: that said, I'm not aware of an official Debian package, but there is a Docker container for Fuseki which I'd prefer. Indeed, that one has no GeoSPARQL support. Nor has the ancient version 2.4.1 of your Gist link

Comment: `bash: ./fuseki-server: No such file or directory` means the script `fuseki-server` was not found in the current directory.

Comment: @AndyS its obvious, my question was to solve the issue, not to get the explanation